# After following the quick start of Spark, why do I get a SNAPSHOT jar file with no class file inside?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm following quick start of Spark 1.6 document, http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

at this step:

# Package a jar containing your application

$ sbt package

...

[info] Packaging {..}/{..}/target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar

What I got is "simple_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" and there is no class inside this jar file. This will cause ClassNotFoundException in the next step when I run spark-submit command.

I have no idea what can cause this issue (why I got a jar file with "SNAPSHOT" and why there is no class in the jar file). Wondering if anyone can point this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, the `SNAPSHOT` occurs because you did not specify a `version` in your sbt file.

Second, how do you know that there is no class inside your jar file? Did you run a `jar tf` on it? If you did and it is indeed empty, then my guess is that you did not store the source files in the expected directory structure, so it didn't pick it up. You can verify this by running `sbt clean compile`. You should see files being compiled if they are in the correct structure.

Comment: I think I specify a version in the sbt file:  
name := "Simple Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.5”
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % “1.6.1”

Comment: Did you `reload` your sbt after saving the file? Because your version is showing as `0.1` from you post

Comment: I extract the jar file to see what it includes and I can only see META-INF file.

Comment: what do you mean by saying reload here? I am really new to sbt and scala.. sorry about this naive question.

Comment: Are you running sbt package or sbt, then package? There is a distinct difference, as the sbt console does not hot reload its own configuration.

Comment: I run "sbt package" directly

Comment: It really sounds like you never hit save on your files....verify everything is saved and re-run

Comment: Thank you Justin! I just figured out the reason. I was in the wrong directory doing sbt package. I have a structure like: simple/simple/src and .sbt, I was at the first simple folder doing package.